# How to generate a list of palindromes without a check

Tags: java, optimization

I'm working on a problem where I'm required to manipulate large lists of palindromes up to a certain number of digits. This should work with numbers up 15 digits. The most common method I've seen for this is iterating through each number and **checking** whether each is a palindrome and then adding that to a list. This is my implementation in java and it works fine.

```
public class Palindrome {

public ArrayList<Long> List = new ArrayList<Long>();
public double d;

public Palindrome(double digits) {
    this.d = digits;

    long dig = (int)(Math.pow(10,digits));

    for (long i = 1; i <= dig; i++) {

        long a = i;
        long b = inverse(a);
        if (a == b) {
            List.add(a);
        }
    }

public long inverse(long x){
    long inv = 0;
    while (x > 0) {
        inv = inv * 10 + x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
    }
    return inv;
}

}
```

Only problem is it's pretty slow when I get to 10+ digit palindromes. I've been considering alternative ways to create this list and one consideration I've had is generating the list of palindromes rather than iterating through each number and checking if it's a palindrome.

I'm still working on paper but the pattern isn't as obvious as I thought I would find it to turn into pseudocode. I'm working it out that for n number of digits, going from i to n, if the number of digits is even, generate numbers from 1 up to [10^(i/2 + 1) - 1]. Then append the reverse of each number to itself. A little stuck on how to do it for the odd digits. That's where I am right now.

I will come back with my own response if I figure this out  and implement the code but in the meantime, I would just like to know if anyone has done this before or has an alternative method I've overlooked that would be more efficient.

**UPDATE**

So I did manage to work out something thanks to all your suggestions. I decided to work with the numbers as strings but contrary to what I intended this has actually increased the runtime :/

```
public class Palindrome2 {
public ArrayList<Long> List = new ArrayList<Long>();
public double d;

public Palindrome2(double digits) {
    this.d = digits;

    for (long n = 1; n <= d; n++) {
        if (n == 1) {
            for (long i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                List.add(i);
            }
        }

        if (n % 2 != 0 && n != 1) {
            long max = (long) Math.pow(10, (n + 1) / 2);
            long min = (long) Math.pow(10, Math.floor(n / 2));

            for (long i = min; i < max; i++) {
                String str = Long.toString(i);
                str = str + removeFirst(reverse(str));
                Long x = Long.parseLong(str);
                List.add(x);
            }
        } else if (n % 2 == 0) {
            long max = (long) (Math.pow(10, Math.floor((n + 1) / 2)) - 1);
            long min = (long) Math.pow(10, (n / 2) - 1);

            for (long i = min; i <= max; i++) {
                String str = Long.toString(i);
                str = str + reverse(str);
                Long x = Long.parseLong(str);
                List.add(x);
            }
        }
    }
}

public String reverse(String x) {
    String rev = new StringBuffer(x).reverse().toString();
    return rev;
}

public String removeFirst(String x) {
    return x.substring(1);
}
```

}

Once again, accurate but still slow :(

Comment: How does `inverse` method look like? It could be the bottleneck

Comment: @Andremoniy Added the inverse method now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Introduction

You need to analyzing the regular pattern for an algorithm roughly before jump into developing, that will saving lot of time, for example:

```
each 1 digit is 1 palindrome, e.g: 1
each 2 digits has 1 palindrome, e.g: 11.

each 3 digits has 10 palindromes, e.g: 101,111,...,191.
each 4 digits has 10 palindromes, e.g: 1001, 1111, ..., 1991.

each 5 digits has 100 palindromes, e.g: 10001, 11011, ..., 19091, ..., 19991.
each 6 digits has 100 palindromes, e.g: 100001, 110011, ..., 190091, ..., 199991.

each 7 digits has 1000 palindromes, e.g: 1000001, ...,1900091,...,1090901, ..., 1999991.
each 8 digits has 1000 palindromes, e.g: 10000001, ...,19000091,...,10900901, ..., 19999991.

....
```

**then** you can write some arrangement algorithm to implement this .

### Implementation

But I can tell you this implementation can optimizing as further, if you using a cache to saving palindromes generated from low digits `palindromes(2)`, then any high digits `palindromes(n>2)` can reusing it.

Maybe it's not *robust* but it pass all my tests on [github](https://github.com/holi-java/api-test/blob/a53094ee85aee1e337ba064d08a16ec3d3eace68/src/test/java/test/algorithm/PalindromeGeneratorTest.java). I left the rest working & optimization to you, and I wish you can done by yourself.

```
private static List<Integer> palindromes(int digits) {
    return palindromes(digits, 0);
}

private static List<Integer> palindromes(int digits, int shifts) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int radix = (int) Math.pow(10, digits - 1);
    int renaming = digits - 2;
    boolean hasRenaming = renaming > 0;
    for (int i = start(digits, shifts); i <= 9; i++) {
        int high = i * radix;
        int low = low(digits, i);
        if (hasRenaming) {
            for (Integer m : palindromes(renaming, shifts + 1)) {
                int ret = high + m * 10 + low;
                if (ret < 0) {
                    return result;
                }
                result.add(ret);
            }
        } else {
            result.add(high + low);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static int low(int digits, int high) {
    return digits > 1 ? high : 0;
}

private static int start(int digits, int shifts) {
    return digits > 1 && shifts == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

### Usage

then you can collect all palindrome numbers as below:

```
           //  v--- min:0, max: 2147447412, count: 121474
List<Integer> all = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)
            .mapToObj(PalindromeTest::palindromes)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Time Cost:**

> 191ms

### Enable Caching

```
public class Palindromes {
    private static final int[] startingNonZerosTable = {
            0,// 0
            0, 1,// 1 2
            10, 10,//3 4
            100, 100, //5 6
            1000, 1000,//7 8
            10000, 10000,// 9 10
            100000, 100000,//11 12
            1000000, 1000000,//13 14
            10000000, 10000000,//15 16
            100000000, 100000000,//17 18
            1000000000, 1000000000//19 20
    };

    private static final int MAX_DIGIT = 9;
    private static final int MIN_DIGIT = 0;
    private static final int RADIX = MAX_DIGIT - MIN_DIGIT + 1;
    private static final int LONG_MAX_DIGITS = 19;
    private static volatile long[][] cache = new long[LONG_MAX_DIGITS + 1][];
    //                                      includes palindromes(0)  ---^

    static {
        cache[0] = new long[0];
        cache[1] = new long[]{0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L};
        cache[2] = new long[]{0L, 11L, 22L, 33L, 44L, 55L, 66L, 77L, 88L, 99L};
    }

    public static LongStream since1(int end) {
        return between(1, end);
    }

    public static LongStream between(int start, int end) {
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end)
                        .mapToObj(Palindromes::of)
                        .flatMapToLong(identity());
    }

    public static LongStream of(int digits) {
        return Arrays.stream(palindromes0(digits))
                     .skip(startingNonZerosTable[digits]);
    }

    private final static long[] palindromes0(int digits) {
        if (cache[digits] != null) {
            return cache[digits];
        }

        long[] result = new long[sizeOf(digits)];
        int size = 0;
        long high = (long) Math.pow(RADIX, digits - 1);

        for (int i = MIN_DIGIT; i <= MAX_DIGIT; i++) {
            for (long mid : palindromes0(digits - 2)) {
                long value = i * high + mid * RADIX + i;
                if (value < 0) {//overflow
                    return cache[digits] = Arrays.copyOf(result, size);
                }
                result[size++] = value;
            }
        }
        return cache[digits] = result;
    }

    private static int sizeOf(int digits) {
        return MAX_DIGIT * (int) Math.pow(RADIX, (digits - 1) >>> 1)
                + startingNonZerosTable[digits];
    }

    //                  v--- java -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m test.algorithm.Palindromes
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Duration duration = timing(() -> {
                         // palindromes[1..15] ---v
            LongSummaryStatistics result = since1(15).summaryStatistics();
            long max = result.getMax();
            long count = result.getCount();

            System.out.printf("Max: %d, Count: %d%n", max, count);
        });

        System.out.printf("Time Elapsed:%s%n", duration);
                                      // ^--- time elapsed: 4s 
    }

    private static Duration timing(Runnable task) {
        long starts = System.currentTimeMillis();
        task.run();
        return Duration.ofMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - starts);
    }
}
```

**Time Cost:**

> palindromes[1..15] time elapsed: 4s

Comment: 191ms is extremely impressive! I was just about to post my solution which doesn't use checks but still ended up increasing the runtime :(. I'll try this right now and confirm if it works :)

Comment: @Sithe my algorithm has not checking the generated number whether is a palindrome number or not. and it can faster if you using a cache to saving the result generated by `palindromes`.

Comment: I just tried this. Works great. However I used LongStream and Longs rather than integers so I can get up to 9999999999. Would you be able to edit that in the code so I can mark this as the solution? This is a really great answer and gave me a bunch to learn about. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: @Sithe I have checked in on [github](https://github.com/holi-java/api-test/blob/150365febd2186af42e34bb42f5ae551010852e4/src/test/java/test/algorithm/PalindromeGeneratorTest.java). but you must using a cache for larger digits.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried working with characters rather than numbers?  You could generate the palindrome as a string of digits and then convert to a number at the end.  Something like this pseudocode:

```
generatePalindrome(size)

    half <- size DIV 2 // Integer division

    result <- ""

    result.append(randomDigitIn(1..9))  // No leading zeros.

    while (result.length <= half)
      result.append(randomDigitIn(0..9))
    endwhile

    if (size is odd)
      result <- result + randomDigitIn(0..9) + result.reverse()
    else
      result <- result + result.reverse()
    endif

    return number.parse(result)

end generatePalindrome()
```

Basically you randomly generate half the palindrome, avoiding leading zeros, insert an extra digit in the middle for odd lengths, append the reversed first half and then parse the digit string into the number format you want.

Comment: This was my next instinct after posting this. I just completed an implementation similar to this and it actually ended up increasing the runtime :(

Answer (score 0):

For odd digit you can simply reuse the palindromes generated at the previous even step , split them in half and insert in the middle all the possible number from 0 to 9.

Let's say you need to generate the palindrom of 3 digit, simply get all the palindromes of 2 digit and add insert all the number from 0 to 9.

We have 22 than we can generate:

- 202
- 212
- 222
- 232
- and so on

Hope my idea is clear:)

Comment: Yes this is how I was thinking about it afterwards too :) But I had trouble with the "insert" part. Instead of inserting, decided to get the reverse of first half of the  numbers then remove the first digit and append it (20, 21, 22, 23) -> (02, 12, 22, 32) -> (2, 2, 2, 2). Is there a way to insert a digit into an integer without converting it to a string?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public class Palindrome
{
  public static ArrayList<Long> calculatePalindromes(int maxLength) {
    ArrayList<Long> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (maxLength <= 0) {
      return result;
    }
    long maxPart = (long)Math.pow(10, maxLength / 2);
    for (long i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      result.add(i);
    }
    for (long i = 1; i < maxPart; ++i) {
      long curHalf = i;
      long curNum = i;
      int curLen = 0;
      while (curHalf != 0) {
        curNum *= 10;
        curNum += curHalf % 10;
        curHalf /= 10;
        ++curLen;
      }
      result.add(curNum);

      // insert numbers from 0 to 9
      if (curLen * 2 + 1 > maxLength) {
        continue;
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        curHalf = i;
        curNum = i;
        curNum *= 10;
        curNum += j;
        while (curHalf != 0) {
          curNum *= 10;
          curNum += curHalf % 10;
          curHalf /= 10;
        }
        result.add(curNum);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

The idea is to insert numbers from `0` to `9` after each `X` and add `reversed(X)` after it so we get `X (1..9) reversed(X)`.

Comment: I just tried this out and it seems to have skipped a lot of palindromes :(

Answer (score 0):

You *can* generate all palindromes in the needed range *without* check, but you will probably face with the memory insufficiency, as storing all these numbesr for 15-length upper number in the list - is a bad idea.

More specifically your code will looks like:

```
        long dig = (long) Math.pow(10, digits / 2);
        int pow = 10;
        int npow = 100;
        for (long i = 1; i <= dig; i++) {
            System.out.println(i * pow + inverse(i));
            System.out.println(i * pow / 10 + inverse(i / 10));
//            list.add(i * pow + inverse(i));
//            list.add(i * pow/10 + inverse(i / 10));
            if (i % pow == 0) {
                pow = npow;
                npow *= 10;
            }
        }
```

I have deliberately commented list adding lines.

The idea is to push into list/output all numbers composed with given half as:

```
XXXY+YXXX
```

and

```
XXX+Y+XXX
```

i.e. generating both cases: odd and even palindromes.